# How to put/insert multiple yanked/deleted lines in vim

Tags: vim, insert, yank

A simple problem that I do not have the right terminology to google to.
I am in visual mode when I delete some lines:

```
aaa

eee
fff
bbb
ccc    
ddd
ggg
hhh
```

from first whitespace in 'b' row I press $ to select to end of line and then down to 'd' line but when I put them in the slot after 'aaa' I get this:

```
aaa
 bbb
 ccc       eee
 ddd       fff



ggg
hhh
```

I want 'e' and 'f' lines to push down, not out. I can do it by copy/paste using the mouse in insert mode but the mouse is not my friend so I would like to know another way of doing it.

Comment: It looks like you are using "visual-block mode" (`<C-v>`, or `<C-q>` if you source `mswin.vim`, which you shouldn't) instead of the correct "visual-line mode" (`V`).

Comment: That fixed it. Obvious like so often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using "visual-block mode" (`<C-v>`, or `<C-q>` if you source `mswin.vim`, which you shouldn't) instead of the correct "visual-line mode" (`V`).